# Flutter in_app_purchase 1.0.6 fails on Android device with error message: "W/BillingClient(15440): getSkuDetails() failed. Response code: 2"

Tags: android, flutter, in-app-purchase

I have set up an in-app-item, and activated it at Google Play Console.

When I `flutter run` on my android device, the app runs but it gives the following error log.

```
W/BillingClient(15440): getSkuDetails() failed. Response code: 2
W/BillingClient(15440): getSkuDetails() failed. Response code: 2
```

According to the link below, this `Response code: 2` means that network connection is down or `BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE`.

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference

As far as I know, my network connection is working fine. If anyone could point to a possible cause of and a solution for this error, it would be appreciated.

Below is my code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:in_app_purchase/in_app_purchase.dart';

const Set<String> _kProductIds = <String>{
  'item_id',
};

class InAppItems with ChangeNotifier {
  final InAppPurchase _inAppPurchase = InAppPurchase.instance;

  InAppItems() {
    setup();
  }

  void setup() async {
    initStoreInfo();
  }

  Future<void> initStoreInfo() async {
    final bool isAvailable = await _inAppPurchase.isAvailable();
    if (!isAvailable) {
      print('Store is not available!');
      return;
    }
    print('Store is available!');

    ProductDetailsResponse productDetailResponse = await _inAppPurchase.queryProductDetails(_kProductIds); // The failure occurs here

    print('productDetailResponse error: ${productDetailResponse.error}');
    print('product details is empty: ${productDetailResponse.productDetails.isEmpty}');
    // other operations...
  }
}
```

And the log around the error looks like this:

```
I/flutter (15440): Store is available!
W/BillingClient(15440): getSkuDetails() failed. Response code: 2
W/BillingClient(15440): getSkuDetails() failed. Response code: 2
I/flutter (15440): productDetailResponse error: null
I/flutter (15440): product details is empty: true
```

If further information is needed, please let me know.

Comment: Simple, just publish the app! The in-app purchases won’t appear until the app is published. Just saving in the draft won’t work. You can publish in alpha or beta. Go to you play store dashboard and press the publish button. 
For more details: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-in-app-purchase-step-by-step-e5611501f723

Comment: Thank you for the comment! Yes, publishing the app solved the issue!